# how can jdeveloper read automatically all the jars downloaded from maven?

Tags: java, maven, jdeveloper

I am using maven , but for example supose that i execute the goal package of some project and maven download the librarys declared in the pom, so after of that i still can't use these librarys because i need go to properties of the project and add librarys manually, so how can jdeveloper add automatically,without have to go to properties and add librarys manually.This of add the librarys in the properties of the project obviously just will be done just one time and every time that somewhere add a new library.

for example en netbeans if we do the same execute the goal package so maven download the librarys but you don't have to go to properties and add these librarys o something like that so you just start use it. so i want the same but in jdeveloper.

Answer (score 0):

Which JDeveloper version are you using?
If you are using 11.1.2.* - can you try the import POM project option in JDeveloper.
http://sriniraman.blogspot.com/2011/06/jdeveloper-project-pom-synchronization.html

Comment: and if i am using jdeveloper 11.1.1.7.0, what can i do?

Comment: i already have seen that way that you use, but here in my work they don't want that i used that version of jdeveloper so, o don't find other way to do that